# nginx subdomain rewrite working but sending 404 header to browser

Tags: php, nginx, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

this problem is freaking me out. I appreciate some help.

I'm using a dynamic subdomain for a multi language site. So I have the following code on nginx:

**pt.site.com** should be **site.com/?lang=pt**

```
if ($host ~* (.*)\.site\.com) {
    set $sub_domain $1;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1?lang=$sub_domain last;
}
```

This actually works. If I access the root folder, everything is ok. If I access something like **pt.site.com/about**, it works - shows the page normally but returns with a 404 error header together.

This is my whole code: http://pastebin.com/yvyChQFv.
Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved :)

```
if ($host ~* (.*)\.site\.com) {
    set $sub_domain $1;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1?lang=$sub_domain?;
}
```